# Running performance analysis for a MSTest test

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2012

I have one or two MSTests that are there to check performance - they take about 5 seconds to run. I've recently been adding async to my library, and now some of those performance tests are very fast (yay!) and some are much slower (boo).

I've used the performance analyzer in VS2012 on some apps in the past to good effect (Analyze -> Start Performance Analysis). I can't figure out if there is a "good" way to run it for one or two of my tests (or, indeed, any of my tests). Is this possible?

I'm using VS2012 and MSTest, .NET 4.5 libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio Test Explorer window has integration with Visual Studio Profiler. You just need to right click on the Test in the Test Explorer window and choose Profile Test.

[image]

Comment: Hmm. That option isn't available to me. I have the pro sku. Is that the difficulty?

Comment: Ok, that is it. Only in premium and above is this integration supported (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx). I'll have to generate my own stand-alone app and analyze it.